# Replace hex in binary file with shell without sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting, sh

I have binary file that I want to replace with shell script `0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd` with `0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44`

I can get `0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd` into shell script like $1 but how can I replace it with `0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44` without sed?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be more clear in your question(like which script you are talking about, please do mention it in your question). Also it is always recommended to mention 3 important things 1- Sample of input, 2- Sample of output 3- efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem in code tags. Please add them clearly and do let us know.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115358/replace-hex-in-binary-file-with-shell-without-sed

Comment: what is the issue in using `sed` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a bash script that does a hexdump of your file, a simple replace and then convert back to a binary file.

You could use an application such as xxd, or hexdump to create a hex dump of your file. This is explained here: [convert binary data to hex in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292645/convert-binary-data-to-hex-in-shell-script)

It looks like xxd creates a hex string that looks like this "aabbccdd" rather than your "0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd" so watch out for that!

To find out how to do a replace, you could look at this answer: [Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command)

You would then want to convert the HEX string back into binary, which is explained here: [linux shell scripting: hex string to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604765/linux-shell-scripting-hex-string-to-bytes)